# PHP: It wants an "object" so I give it and object and then it errors saying it wanted an "array" what gives?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Im confused. Working with the Cardano API (v1) using [a PHP wrapper](https://github.com/zech001/Cardano-Api-PHP-Wrapper).

The `createNewTransaction($source, $destination, $spendingPassword)` function requires parameters in the form of an array:

```
// source of funds (array)
    $source = array(
                'accountIndex'  => $wallet_idx,
                'walletId'      => $wallet_id
            );

    // destination for funds (array)
    $destination = array(
                'address' => $banker,
                'amount'  => $lovelace
            );

    // spending pass
    $spendingPassword = get_user_meta('1', 'spending_pass', true);

    // transaction
    $client->createNewTransaction($source, $destination, $spendingPassword);
```

So then im returned this error from the API:

> Array ( [status] => error [diagnostic] => Array (
>   [validationError] => Error in $: When parsing the constructor Payment
>   of type Cardano.Wallet.API.V1.Types.Payment expected Object but got
>   Array. ) [message] => JSONValidationFailed )

So then, I looked up how to turn an array into an object thinking that would solve my problem. So I did this:

```
   $o_source = (object) $source;
   $o_destination = (object) $destination;
```

and then sent it back to the API to see if the transaction would go through, but I got another error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Cardano::createNewTransaction() must be of the type array, object
>   given...

So, now Im confuseed, I thought I had originally sent it an array but then it said it wanted an object. I dont get it!

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

[The code from the linked library](https://github.com/zech001/Cardano-Api-PHP-Wrapper/blob/master/cardano.php#L131-L136) looks something like:

```php
public function createNewTransaction(
    array $source,
    array $destination,
    string $spendingPassword
): array {
    $groupPolicy = 'OptimizeForSecurity';
    return self::jsonDecode($this->post(
        '/api/v1/transactions' .
        '?source=' . $source .
        '?destination=' . $destination .
        '?groupingPolicy=' . $groupPolicy .
        '?spendingPassword=' . $spendingPassword
    ), true);
}
```

If you run this code, then `$source` and `$destination` would be cast from arrays to the string "Array". This is what the API is complaining about, it probably expected something other than the string "Array" as the value of the `source` parameter.

I recommend that you look for another library, or implement the API calls yourself, because this library has no chance of working correctly in its current state.

Comment: Can you help me figure out what's wrong with the existing library? I'm not familiar with CURL and this seems like it's over my head for my current skill level.